# Is it possible to upload files along with initialization script on EC2 instance when running it with AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have `nginx` configuration files which I would like to deploy on my `Ubuntu` `EC2` instance. I create instance using `AWS CLI`:

```
  aws ec2 run-instances --instance-type t2.micro \
    --count 1 \
    --image-id ami-0f8b8babb98cc66d0 \
    --key-name "$key_name" \
    --tag-specifications "ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=$name}]" \
    --query "Instances[0].{$instance_fields_selection}" \
    --user-data 'file://ec2-setup'
```

This mostly works as expected: `ec2-setup` script creates some folders, installs some packages and does `reboot`. But I still have to upload my `nginx` config files manually through `scp`. `--user-data` option seems to be intended for uploading files, but in fact it is used for passing initialization script. Is it possible to toss normal non-executable file on instance when creating it using `AWS CLI`?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your user-data script you can specify all commands you need to prepare the OS. Then, it's inside the user-data script that you'll scp something.

However, you can't inject files inside your instance without scp or s3 commands in your user-data script.